# Redirect passing the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect from one component to another and passing the props between them.

```
function MyFirstComponent({survey}) {
....
// There is a button that triggers the below if clause. The redirect works but it seems the state is not sent.
    if (surveyPage === true) {
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/detail',
            state: { survey: survey }
        }}

    }

    return("something")

}
```

`MySecondComponent` is the component to which the user is redirected to.
The redirection **works** but the props are not sent.
In fact, is I `console.log(survey)`, I get undefined.

```
function MySecondComponent({survey}){
    console.log(this.props.location.survey) // This is "undefined"
    return (
        "test"
    )
}
```

export default Details

Comment: One issue what I see is in functional component there is no `this` as you use.

Comment: The same problem appears even if I `console.log(survey)` without his

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, props don't exist on `this` in a functional component, so if you weren't deconstructing the props you'd access the property you're interested in like this:

`console.log(props.location.state.survey)`

Since you ARE deconstructing the props, the `props` property isn't accessible any more, only the deconstructed properties. You can get directly to the value you're interested in like so:

```
function MySecondComponent({ location: { state } }){
    console.log(state.survey)
    return (
        "test"
    )
}
```

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-microservice-02gqq)

Comment: If I do the `{ location: { survey } }` it gives me an error of `undefined` for `survey`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The actual path to the object would be `props.location.state.survey`. So to deconstruct it would look like `{ location: { survey: { state } } }`, which is a bit of a mouthful. I've updated my answer and linked to a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like below.

```html
function MyFirstComponent(props) {
    if (surveyPage === true) {
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/detail',
            state: { survey: props.survey }
        }}

    }

    return("something")

}


function MySecondComponent(props){
    console.log(props.location.state.survey) 
    return (
        "test"
    )
}
```